# moment.js, how to get day of week number

Tags: date, momentjs

I have a moment date object, and want to get the selected day number (0-6) or (1-7).

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
var aaa = moment(date).day();
```

help me with this please

Comment: Why use moment? `new Date('2015-07-02').getDay()` should work. This accepts a date string, milliseconds since epoch ánd a Date object and requires no library :)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Define "doesn't work".

```js
const date = moment("2015-07-02"); // Thursday Feb 2015
const dow = date.day();
console.log(dow);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This prints "4", as expected.

Comment: For those who are curious, 2015-07-02 was a Thursday. Meaning, 0 -> Sunday. Cheers

Comment: The important bit here is that this is locale dependant, if your locale is set to a country that has mondays as start of week, 0 means monday. - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/

Comment: using `.isoWeekday()` and then converting to required locale is a better choice. This answer is good if you [control the locale explicitly](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) in a multi locale environment

Answer (score 131):

If you are specifically looking for the 1-7 approach...

This is the [ISO weekday number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).  moment.js has also taken this into account.  Use [`isoWeekday()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-weekday/)

```js
console.log(moment().isoWeekday()); // returns 1-7 where 1 is Monday and 7 is Sunday
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Seeing as I wrote this answer on a Tuesday, today this gives me a 2.

Comment: It's also work adding that, to get the DOW with Sunday as day 1, would be var dow = moment().isoWeekday() % 7 where Sunday is 0.

Answer (score 25):

I think this would work

```
moment().weekday(); //if today is thursday it will return 4
```

Comment: weekday is locale aware, thursday could be 3 depending which locale is set. See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/

Answer (score 7):

You can get this in 2 way using moment and also using Javascript

```js
const date = moment("2015-07-02"); // Thursday Feb 2015
const usingMoment_1 = date.day();
const usingMoment_2 = date.isoWeekday();

console.log('usingMoment: date.day() ==> ',usingMoment_1);
console.log('usingMoment: date.isoWeekday() ==> ',usingMoment_2);


const usingJS= new Date("2015-07-02").getDay();
console.log('usingJavaSript: new Date("2015-07-02").getDay() ===> ',usingJS);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

From the docs page, notice they have these helpful headers

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/
*(I didn't see them at first)*

With header sections for:

- Date of Month
- Day of Week
- etc

.

```
  var now = moment();
  var day  = now.day();
  var date = now.date(); // Number
```