# How do I display a different message depending on what day it is with Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, momentjs

I am using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to try and display a different message, depending on what day it is.

**For example, if it's:**

- Monday I'd like it to say "It's Monday!"
- Tuesday I'd like it to say "Happy Tuesday!"

And so on...

So far, I have this call: **moment().format('dddd')** which I know displays the day of the week perfectly but I don't know how to display a different message depending on what day of the week it is.

Thanks for your time in advance for looking into this.

Ollie

Comment: Use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183558/moment-js-how-to-get-day-of-week-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a switch case:

```js
var msg = '';

switch (moment().format('dddd')) {
                case 'Monday':
                    {
                        msg = 'It\'s Monday!';
                        break;
                    }
                case 'Tuesday':
                    {
                        msg = 'Happy Tuesday!';
                        break;
                    }
                    // etc...
            }

document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = msg;
```

```html
<div id='message'></div>
```

Comment: Nice! How would I then display the output in a div (and give it a class)?

Comment: Are you using pure javascript or AngularJS?

Comment: Thanks! Can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to determine the current day, even without moment.js:

```js
console.log("Happy " + ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"][new Date().getUTCDay()-1])
```

Below is a more advanced example:

```js
var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
var day = new Date().getUTCDay() - 1;

function getMessageOfTheDay() {
  switch (day) {
    case 0:
      return "Moody " + days[day];
      break;
    case 1:
      return "Trippy " + days[day];
      break;
    case 2:
      return "Weeping " + days[day];
      break;
    case 3:
      return "Thundering " + days[day];
      break;
    case 4:
      return "Freaky " + days[day];
      break;
    case 5:
      return "Salty " + days[day];
      break;
    case 6:
      return "Super " + days[day];
      break;
    default:
      return "Happy " + days[day];
  }
}

var classes = document.getElementById("messageOfTheDay").getAttribute('class').split(' ');
classes.push('day-' + days[day].toLowerCase());
document.getElementById("messageOfTheDay").setAttribute('class', classes.join(' '))
document.getElementById("messageOfTheDay").innerHTML = getMessageOfTheDay();

console.log("Below is the HTML code for or `h1`. Notice the added day-{DAY-OF-WEEK}");
console.log(document.getElementById("messageOfTheDay"));
```

```html
<h1 id="messageOfTheDay" class="hello world"></h1>
```

Just updated the above snippet to a function which returns the string. Know you can easily choose to `alert`, `console.log` or insert it in your page as i do above.

Comment: Thanks! So if to have a different message on Monday and Tuesday, would I do this:

console.log("Happy " + ["Monday"][new Date().getUTCDay()-1])
console.log("It's " + ["Tuesday"][new Date().getUTCDay()-1])

Comment: How would I then display the console log output in html and give it a class?

Comment: Do you want the class to change with each day? My example above simply delivers the message to an otherwise static element.

Comment: I would love more control yes.

Comment: Just made an update that displays how to insert a class

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
if(moment().format('dddd') == "Monday")
    //do something
if(moment().format('dddd') == "Tuesday")
    //do something else
```

Comment: What would I then put after the if statements to display a message in a div?

Comment: document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML = "hello world"

Comment: YES that's what I wanted. Returns a lot of code and there's a lot of repetition. Can it be cleaned up at all?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample. You can then use the `myMessage` for what you need

```
var myMessage = '';
switch(moment().format('dddd')){
    case 'Monday':
        myMessage = "It's Monday !";
        break;
    case 'Tuesday':
        myMessage = "Happy Tuesday !";
        break;
    case ...
}
```