# How to transform a date into day of the week counting from 0 on Sunday with Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am currently using `const weekday = moment().isoWeekday()` to get which day of the week it is. It starts with Sunday as 0 and ends with Saturday as 6.

Now, I am getting a date in the following format, as a string: `06-07-2020`

How could I use moment to find out which day of the week (in numbers as above, starting with Sunday as 0) this date is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [moment.js, how to get day of week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183558/moment-js-how-to-get-day-of-week-number)

Comment: partially. it does get a number but not the right one (it should be 1 for today, I'm getting 0). And at times, the return value is NaN.

Comment: If you're getting NaN, it doesn't recognise the date you're putting in. moment("06-07-2020", "MM-DD-YYYY")

Answer (score 2):

You may easily get the day of the week using the .day() function with momentjs.

```js
const date = moment("06-07-2020","DD-MM-YYYY") //Today
let day_of_week = date.day()
console.log(day_of_week)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The format I am using is ```06-07-2020```. Moreover, this will sometimes yield a number, sometimes yield NaN

Comment: @kiabbott. 
It is working quite fine without pushing it out any NaN, I have tested on various values.

Comment: `06-07-2020` is ambiguous. Is it in MM-DD-YYYY format (June 7th) or in DD-MM-YYYY format (July 6th) ?

Comment: @JeremyThille, I believe she was referring to DD-MM-YYYY because I provided the same date in order of YYYY-MM-DD in the previous version of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the day function is returning NaN then it's not reading your date properly. Tell Moment what date format it should expect, before asking it what day it is:

```
moment("06-07-2020", "MM-DD-YYYY").day();
```

OR

```
moment("06-07-2020", "DD-MM-YYYY").day();
```